# Sprockets append_path does not add to SASS load_path

Tags: windows-7, sass, compass-sass, sprockets

I am serving my Compass-powered SASS files through a Rack server using Sprockets in Windows 7 (development environment only). When I append paths to Sprockets it doesn't seem to add these to SASS load path.

As I understand it from docs in [sprockets-sass](https://github.com/petebrowne/sprockets-sass) `append_path` should add the path to SASS `load_path` automatically.

I have `base/sass/base.scss` in a project specific component directory (listed below), and in this file I am trying to include all scss files from the *common* component. If I use the relative path (`../common/sass/*`) in `@include` it works, but when I let SASS to look for it in the load_path I get the following error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: common/sass/*
Load paths:
  Sass::Globbing::Importer
  C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
  C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
  C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-magick-0.1.4/lib/stylesheets
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  (in C:/repos/test/project/components/base/sass/base.scss)
```

As you can see, only the paths added by compass and compass-magick are listed in the load path, and I would like it to look in `C:/repos/test/project/components` as well.

My rack server setup looks like this:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

COMPONENT_DIR = "../../components" # -> C:/repos/test/project/components
GENERATED_CSS_DIR = "public/generated-css"

Compass.configuration do |compass|
  compass.output_style = :compressed
end

compiler = Rack::Builder.new do
  map "/#{GENERATED_CSS_DIR}" do
    environment = Sprockets::Environment.new
    environment.append_path File.expand_path(COMPONENT_DIR)
    environment.cache = Sass::CacheStores::Memory.new
    run environment
  end
end.to_app

@server = Rack::Server.new({:app => compiler, :Port => 9292})

Thread.new do
  loop do
    if $stdin.gets.nil?
      @server.server.shutdown
      Process.exit
    end
  end
end

@server.start
```

The bundle installs the following gems:

- rack (1.4.1)
- sass (3.1.15)
- sass-globbing (1.0.0.rc.2)
- compass (0.12.1)
- compass-magick (0.1.4)
- sprockets (2.3.1)
- sprockets-helpers (0.4.0)
- sprockets-sass (0.7.0)

I would be very greatful for any insight or pointers on how I can solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need something like;

```
compass.add_import_path File.expand_path(File.join(COMPONENT_DIR, "components"))
```

inside your `Compass.configuration do |compass|` block?